# Migrate svn from Assembla to Atlassian

Tags: svn, assembla

I'm trying to migrate my subversion repo to Atlassian. Atlassian requires the imported repo dump to have a root directory with the same name as the project per project key. Let's say my project key in Atlassian is FOOBAR, then the repo dump should contain /FOOBAR for all revisions. It should also contain trunk, branches and tags subdirectories.

To rewrite the Assembla svn dump, I did this:

```
cat foobar-assembla.dump | svn-dump-reloc "/" "FOOBAR" > foobar-atlassian.dump
```

Then I tried testing it:

```
svnadmin create test
cat foobar-atlassian.dump | svnadmin load test
```

That produced an error message:

```
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '0-0', path 'FOOBAR/trunk'
 * adding path : FOOBAR/trunk ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

Using a text editor with all conversion options turned off:

1. Replace all instances of `Node-path: trunk` with `Node-path: FOOBAR/trunk`.
2. In the revision in which `FOOBAR/trunk` is created, manually add an entry immediately before the one that adds `FOOBAR/trunk` that creates `FOOBAR`, `FOOBAR/branches` and `FOOBAR/tags`.

I understand this may not work in some cases, such as when `Node-path: trunk` occurs within a file itself. But it worked in this case and should work in most others.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the dump file does not contain any transaction that would create the FOOBAR directory itself.

Try running `svn mkdir file://$PWD/test/FOOBAR` just before the `svnadmin load test`.

To give credit where it's due, I got this tip from http://dotslashstar.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/svn-hack-insert-missing-trunk-root.html

Comment: +1: Although I found my own way using a text editor (nano), I can see how `svn mkdir` **before** `svnadmin load` might work.